# Unix Grep command

Tags: unix, shell, grep

I have to search from codebase of lines having following pattern:

```
"get_token , get_token"
```

For example the below line 'type' should be listed:

```
fn1(string.get_token(), string1.get_token());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -R ".*get_token(),.*get_token()" *
```

Answer (score 1):

```
egrep '(get_token).*\1'
```

Modify as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep "get_token.*,.*get_token" *
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E -n 'get_token.*?get_token' *
```

Answer (score 0):

| grep "get_token.*,.*get_token"